# Carboard.c:12:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c

When I compile my code the two connected functions below the programme doesn't work properly. When I compile the code on my pc I get no errors yet once I load one of the boards and return to the main menu option 1-2 works properly but I cannot use the third option. In other words I cannot quit the game. Instead it prints "Good bye!" and asks me to choose an option. This only occurs when I go into 'do while' loop and choose the third option there. When I compile the code in Terminal I get the error message provided in the title somehow. Same errors occur in Terminal. Any ideas how to solve this problem? I can provide additional code pieces if need be.

First one:

```
int main() {

printf("Welcome to Car Board \n");
printf("-------------------- \n");
printf("1. Play game \n");
printf("2. Show student's information \n");
printf("3. Quit \n\n");

showMenu();

}

void showMenu(){
  Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
  int choice = validateNumber();
  if(choice == 1){

    showCommands();
    initialiseBoard(board);
    displayBoard(board, NULL);

    printf("load <g>\n");
    printf("quit\n\n");

    playGame();

  }

  if (choice == 2){

    showStudentInformation();

  }

  if (choice == 3){

    printf("Good Bye!\n\n");

}

  else showMenu();
}
```

Second one:

```
void playGame()
{
  Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
  char str1[] = {"load 1"};
  char str2[] = {"load 2"};
  char str3[] = {"quit"};
  char * choice;


do {
    choice = validateString();
    if (strcmp(choice, str1) == 0) {

        printf("\n");
        loadBoard(board, BOARD_1);
        displayBoard(board, NULL);
        playGame();

    }

    if(strcmp(choice, str2) == 0){

        printf("\n");
        loadBoard(board, BOARD_2);
        displayBoard(board, NULL);
        playGame();

    }

    if(strcmp(choice, str3) == 0){

        printf("\n");
        printf("Welcome to Car Board \n");
        printf("-------------------- \n");
        printf("1. Play game \n");
        printf("2. Show student's information \n");
        printf("3. Quit \n\n");
        showMenu();

    }

    else {
        printf("Invalid input\n\n");
        playGame();

    }

}
while(strcmp(choice, str1) != 0 && strcmp(choice, str2) != 0 && strcmp(choice, str3) != 0);


}
```

Comment: Try adding `return 0` in end of main to get rid of the warning

Comment: Show the code for `validateNumber`

Comment: `int validateNumber() {

    char line[LINE_LEN + EXTRA_SPACES];
    char *end;
    int input;

    do {
        printf("Please enter your choice:");
        fgets(line, LINE_LEN + EXTRA_SPACES, stdin);

        if (line[strlen(line) - 1] != '\n') {
            readRestOfLine();
            continue;
        }

        line[strlen(line) - 1] = 0;

        input = strtol(line, &end, 0);
    }

    while(*end);

    return input;

}`

Comment: The 'Welcome' message and following lines should clearly be in a separate function to avoid repetition.  You should probably use `else if (choice == 2)` and `else if (choice == 3)` to avoid having choices 1 and 2 re-enter `showMenu()` (recursive call) from inside `showMenu()`.  In `playGame()`, it is not clear why you redisplay the menu when the user asks to quit;  you probably have a problem with the (recursive) call to `playGame()` too.  You should probably be using `else if` here too.  You need to rethink your code to avoid recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding return 0 in end of main to get rid of the warning

Further you should get rid of all the recursive calls. Instead of

```
void showMenu(){
    Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
    int choice = validateNumber();
    if(choice == 1){
        showCommands();
        initialiseBoard(board);
        displayBoard(board, NULL);
        printf("load <g>\n");
        printf("quit\n\n");
        playGame();
    }

   if (choice == 2){   
       showStudentInformation();
   }

   if (choice == 3){   
       printf("Good Bye!\n\n");
   }
   else showMenu();  // Recursive call
}
```

Try

```
void showMenu(){
    Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];

    while(1) {   // Loop until choice is 3

        int choice = validateNumber();
        if(choice == 1){
            showCommands();
            initialiseBoard(board);
            displayBoard(board, NULL);
            printf("load <g>\n");
            printf("quit\n\n");
            playGame();
        }

       else if (choice == 2){   
           showStudentInformation();
       }

       else if (choice == 3){   
           printf("Good Bye!\n\n");

           return;   // End the function
       }
   }
}
```

The same idea should be applied to the `PlayGame` function to get rid of recursive calls. Also don't call `ShowMenu` from `PlayGame` - just do a `return`

Comment: Thanks so much! Solved my problem I am fairly new to C programming language as you could guess. Trying to get done with my assignment. I could use a couple more helps in the future! Thanks again!